# $i^{th}$ root(s) of unity

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, geometric-interpretation

If we define $S:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z^n=1\}$ (i.e. the $n^{th}$ roots of unity), then $|S|=n$ (i.e. we have $n$ of them). We can even go as far as to say: $$S=\{z_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\cap[1,n]\}=\{e^{2\pi i/k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\cap[1,n]\}$$
Plotting these points on an Argand diagram shows the above point, namely that the plot looks symmetric across the real axis, and has rotational symmetry order $n$. It follows that, if we let $n\to\infty$, the plot of points tends towards being a circle centred on the origin, radius $1$.

But $z^i$, and even $z^{1/i}$, are both (possibly) well-defined ideas, **so can we talk about the $i^{th}$ roots of unity? How many of them are there? What geometric interpretation is there when we talk about them, and can we analogously look at the $2i^{th}$ roots, etc.?**

I know that $z^{1/i}:=e^{(1/i)\log{z}}$, so $z^{1/i}=1$ means that we search for solutions to $(1/i)\log{z}=0 \Rightarrow \log{z}=0$.

I guess a similar question is: **what geometric/insightful interpretation is there to the fact that $i^i=e^{(-\pi+4k)/2}$ (for $k\in\mathbb{Z})$?**

*Edit: turns out that I can't multiply things by $0$ correctly... mistake fixed, thanks.*

Comment: Are you sure $\,z^i\,$ is "well defined", just like that? Please do give its definition...

Comment: I thought it was, but it if is not please do let me know!

Comment: Well, I thought one might want to define $$z^i=e^{i\text{Log}\,z}$$ but then the problem is that the complex logarithm is a multivalued "function", so...Can you see the problem here?

Comment: This would require a geometric interpretation of $z\mapsto z^i$. Here is [a plot](http://www3.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP17471g6c1ag4i5b19hcg00003i863i149c82d870?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=45&w=396.&h=182.).

Comment: Ah, I see now! Could we not solve this by taking the value of $z$ with the smallest argument between $-\pi$ and $\pi$ or something? Or is my question completely voided by this?

Comment: @Blue ? Why that anyone would think that $$\frac1i\text{Log}\,z=0\implies \text{Log} z=i\;\;??$$ What is undoubtedly true is $$\frac1i\text{Log} z=0\implies \text{Log}\,z=0$$ , as would happen in any field...

Comment: Yes @Tim, that could make the trick: in mathematical lingo, that's called *choosing a branch cut for the logarithmic function*. You can google "branch cut logarithm" .

Comment: Right on, @Blue . Thanks.

Comment: OK, so Wikipedia seems to think that we can define $\log{z}$ in a meaningful way, by defining one solution and then saying that all others are just that one $+2k\pi i$.
In this case, is there now any answer to my question?

Comment: Whatever the i-th roots of unity are, $e^{2\pi}$ *is* one. Do you count this as meaningful? :)

Comment: $e^{2\pi n}, n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: If $n$ is a natural number, then $z^n$ takes only one value. If $p/q$ is a reduced rational number, then $z^{p/q}$ can take $q$ different values. In the case of arbitrary non-rational complex value $w$, $z^w$  can take any of a set of countably many different values.

Comment: but surely we can look at just its principal value? I didn't realise that this question was quite such a pointless one apparently...

Comment: An error in your reasoning: when you say that $e^{(1/i)\log z}=1\implies (1/i)\log z=0$. Actually $e^{(1/i)\log z}=1\implies (1/i)\log z=2\pi i n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $\lg(z)$ to be the standard branch cut of $\ln$, discontinuous on the negative reals. Now since $\exp$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$, $\exp(y)=z\implies y=\lg(z)+(2\pi i)n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So if you would like $z^i$ to mean $\exp(i\cdot\lg(z))$, then $$\begin{align}z^i=1&\implies\exp(i\cdot\lg(z))=1\\
&\implies i\cdot\lg(z)=\lg(1)+(2\pi i)n\\
&\implies \lg(z)= 2\pi n\\
&\implies z=\exp(2\pi n)\\
\end{align}$$

So the collection of $i$th roots of unity is countably infinite, consisting of the following positive real numbers: $$\{\ldots,e^{-4\pi},e^{-2\pi},1,e^{2\pi},e^{4\pi},\ldots\}$$
Repeating this for general complex roots, the $w$th roots of unity are the countable collection $$\{\exp(2\pi i n/w)\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ (which may be merely finite if $w$ is such that there is overlap in this collection.)

Comment: (...which occurs if and only if $w$ is real and rational.)

Answer (score 0):

One considers not so much the cyclotomic numbers $cis(2\pi m/n)$, but rather the table of chords $C(m/n) = 1-cis(2\pi m/n)$.  $cis() = cos() + i sin()$.

It's a pretty straight-forward proof that the intersection between the set of spans of the cyclotomics, and the set of fractional numbers (Z/Z), is the set of reals.

Using the further item that the product of numbers $C(m/n)$ for 0

So if you determine that the chord of an angle is 4-sqrt(13), then it must be irrational.