# What is the cardinality of the set of $x$-th roots of unity?

Tags: complex-numbers, cardinals, roots-of-unity

Consider the set of $x$-th roots of unity.  What is its cardinality?

Formally, consider $x \in \mathbb{C}$, and let

$S_x = \{y \in \mathbb{C} \; : \;$ there exist $k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$ x(\ln y + 2\pi i k) = 2\pi i m\} \}$.

This is based of multi-valued definition of $\ln$, as per a suggestion in the comments below. What is the cardinality of $S_x$?

For example, when $x = n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $S_n$ is just $n$. When $x=0$, the solutions are all $y \in \mathbb{C}$ except $y=0$.

What happens in other cases?

Comment: When $x=0$, isn't every $y\in\Bbb C$ a solution?

Comment: Since logarithms are multivalued in $\Bbb C^*$, is this the correct interpretation of $S_x$? Define $S_x = \{ y\in \Bbb C\colon {}$there exist $k,m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $x(\log y + 2\pi i k) = 2\pi i m\}$.

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes, fixed

Comment: Alternatively, *if* you're interested in a single-valued interpretation of $y^x$, then this answer becomes relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/392052/87023